# Checking if a View == null before setting onClickListener

Tags: android

I usually create the `initialize()` function and functions for setting on-click listeners, and then I call these functions from an Activity's `onCreate()`. When I call `someView.setOnClickListener(...)` in a function, should I check if the `someView == null` or not? I know, that it `!= null`, but I need an advice about coding style. Which is the best practice?
Here is an example:

```
...
public class SomeActivity extends Activity
{
    private ImageButton someButton;
    private Intent someIntent;

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_alarm);        
        initialize();
        setSomeButtonHandler();
    }

    public void initialize()
    {
        someButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.someButton);
    }

    public void setSomeButtonHandler()
    {
        if(someButton != null) //Should I check this?
        {
            someIntent = new Intent(SomeActivity.this, SomeButtonActivity.class);
            someButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    startActivity(someIntent);
                }
           });
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: No you don't, remove those for readability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once `setContentView()` has been called, you will never get a null View provided you are looking in the correct layout and the View exists in that layout.

You will only get a null if you're looking for a View by passing the wrong ID, or are looking for it inside a different layout, like a Dialog's or something.

So if you design your application well and keep all this in mind while coding, you should not need these null checks. I have personally never used them in over 2 years of working on Android and haven't had any problems because of it.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need this sanity check.

If findViewById returns null, it better crash the application because it means that you are not using the right XML or ID. Solve it when crashing in debug and won't be null again.

Answer (score 0):

you can use null checking for testing purpose. the `findViewByID` method returns null when it doesn't find any view. For example if you use wrong id or by any chance try to access the child before `setContentView`.

So if you are sure that you have done everything right then no need to check. But if there is any chance of mistake you can use it for testing

like

```
if(buttton == null)
   show a warning
else
   do work
```